# How do I use the BearerToken in all subsequent calls to the API after authenticating using username & password

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, access-token, bearer-token

I have a CustomAuthenticationProvider that does a POST request to an API with username and password for authentication and the API returns an access token with expiry time.

Where do I set this token, so I can use the same token to make further calls to the API as long as the user is logged in. I also wanted to validate the token for expiry time before making another request.

Is it right approach to add the token to a customAuthenticationToken that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and set it in the SecurityContext.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: what client library are you using?

Comment: It's a Spring boot Application(v3.0.2) with Spring Security configured. This is a custom application that should be able to connect with an internal application that exposes REST end points for user authentication and make some additional request for fetching data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you need to call another REST API, then you need to set up an http client. Since you use Spring Boot 3, [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html) is a default option, but the flow is the same for any client.

You basically store your token anywhere in memory, implement isExpired check and refresh logic.

```
class TokenStorage {
    private String token;

    void refreshToken() { 
        var newToken = ...;
        this.token = newToken;
    } 

    boolean isExpired() { ... }

    String getToken() { 
        return token;
    } 
}
```

And then setup your client with custom filter so that everytime you call API, it checks whether token is expired and refreshes it if so.

Comment: Thank you,  I will do a custom class for storage.  But, storing the token in memory: do you mean user session? is it possible to store the token in user session / security context.

Comment: This is memory on the client. No session on client. Also no session on server because JWT encourages stateless. JWT is validated will every call received by the server.

Comment: @Kalry Oh, sorry I read you question completely wrong. So you want to authenticate user and give them your own session ID, but also get a 3rd party access token using the same user credentials (username + password)? And then make calls to that 3rd party using users access token?

Comment: John to you question, we have to run this application on Tomcat with no database. So, I need to find a way to store the token in securitycontextholder, like how we store the usernamepassword authentication token.

Comment: @voismager I was asking if I can use a Session ID to do that. But, my friend suggested, I can put the access token in the User Object itself and use it on further requests. I am going to try and see if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

The token needs to be in the 'authorization' header for all calls. The value should be 'Bearer ' + token. If you are using a browser it gets a bit messy - let me know.

To add the authorization bearer header to all calls from Spring Boot depends on the sort of client, eg

```
HttpClient httpClient= new HttpClient()
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

Where the `token` is stored as a, probably `static`, variable somewhere.

In the server side you need a Filter that validates the token and marks the request as authorised - quite a bit of work - look [here](https://medium.com/@xoor/jwt-authentication-service-44658409e12c)

Comment: The server side has the implementation to validate the token. But, in the client side (provided its a spring boot application) where do i store this token? Or do I have to authenticate the user everytime a request is made to access resources, get the access token and then create the authorization header.

Comment: You need to add the following header to all calls: "authorization": "Bearer " + token. I'll update the answer